# Qual é a abordagem certa para pegar o click/posição no RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, onclick

Qual é a abordagem certa para pegar o click no RecyclerView?

1 - Dentro do onBindViewHolder usar a position, mesmo que dentro dos métodos setOnClickListener, o que transforma a variavel position em FINAL;
2 - Dentro do onBindViewHolder usar o holder.getAdapterPosition(), mesmo que dentro dos métodos setOnClickListener, o que transforma a variavel holder em FINAL;
3 - Algum outro jeito que envolva interface/outros jeitos, como neste [exemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick/26196831#26196831). [Outro.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296708/get-clicked-item-and-its-position-in-recyclerview)

EXEMPLO:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        holder.imagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "posicao "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "posicao "+holder.getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É sempre complicado dizer qual é a "abordagem certa", ela pode ser melhor num caso e pior noutros.

Os `onClickListener` são atribuídos à *view*. Quem é responsável por facultar a *view* ao *adapter* é a classe *ViewHolder*.
Julgo, assim, que deve ser aí que eles devem ser atribuídos.

Por outro lado, atribuir os *"listeners"* no `onBindViewHolder()` fará com que eles sejam atribuídos sempre que uma linha é apresentada na RecyclerView.
Ao atribuí-los no construtor do ViewHolder eles serão reaproveitados, sendo atribuídos apenas uma vez.

Para obter a posição deve<sup>(1)</sup> usar o método [getAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()).

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
                                 implements View.OnClickListener{

    private final ImageView imageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //Atribui o listener ao layout da linha.
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        // no entanto ele pode ser aplicado a qualquer uma das views dele.
        //imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //Implementa View.OnClickListener
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Elemento " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicado.");
    }
}
```

O `onCreateViewHolder()` do *adapter* seria assim:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_item, viewGroup, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}
```

O método `onBindViewHolder()` deverá apenas atribuir os valores às *views*.

Esta abordagem pode ser melhorada de forma a que o código a executar, quando for clicado um item, seja externo ao *adapter*.

Defina uma interface a implementar pela classe que irá executar o código, quando for clicado um item:

```
public interface ItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

Adicione ao *adapter* um campo e o respectivo *setter* para guardar uma instância que implemente essa interface:

```
private static ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

Altere a *ViewHolder* de forma a chamar o método `onItemClick()` dessa instância.

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
                                 implements View.OnClickListener{

    private final ImageView imageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //Atribui o listener ao layout da linha.
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        // no entanto ele pode ser aplicado a qualquer uma das views dele.
        //imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //Implementa View.OnClickListener
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(itemClickListener != null) {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Agora é possível declarar o código, a executar quando for clicado um item, no local onde é instanciado o *adapter*

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Elemento " + position + " clicado.");
    }
});
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> - Justificado por este trecho da [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()):

> (...)Sometimes, you may need to get the exact adapter position to do some actions in response to user events. In that case, you should use this method which will calculate the Adapter position of the ViewHolder.
>
> (...)Por vezes pode ser necessário obter a posição exacta do adaptador para fazer algumas acções em resposta a eventos do usuário. Nesse caso, você deve usar este método que irá calcular a posição do ViewHolder no adaptador.

Comment: E se eu quiser que uma imageview tenha um setOnClick e nesse onClick ela precise abrir uma nova tela?
É só passar a lista no construtor do viewHolder e setar o onClick no imageView normalmente?

Comment: por exemplo, o notifyDataSetChanged(); funciona normal?

Comment: Eu adicionei o listener ao layout, mas pode ser adicionado a qualquer uma das views desse layout. Se necessita de outros dados para construir o listener passe-os no construtor. Em relação ao `notifyDataSetChanged()` poderá haver situações em que o método `getAdapterPosition()` pode retornar *NO_POSITION* mas julgo que não será o caso durante uma chamada a `onCreateViewHolder()`.

Comment: O 'notifyDataSetChanged();' só atualiza a lista que está na classe adapter, mas não atualiza a lista que está no viewHolder.
Vou ter que manter duas listas e atualizá-las ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: vou ter que manter uma instancia global do holder no adapter e sempre que chamar notifyDataSetChanged eu atualizo também a lista do holder...
isso não é gambiarra?

Comment: Ainda não percebi porque necessita de passar a lista para o viewholder.

Comment: no clique da lista eu dou um get(posicao) e passo o objeto pra a próxima activity.

Comment: Não precisa, melhor não deve passar a lista para o viewholder. Implemente um método no adapter que retorne o item em determinada posição, chame-o no viewholder depois de obter a posição com `getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: Salvou minha vida. Esse é o melhor método.

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo setar uma TAG para pegar a posição correta.

Por exemplo:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.imagem.setTag(position);
        holder.imagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int clickPosition = (int) view.getTag();

                Toast.makeText(context, "posicao "+clickPosition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Estou usando o Glide e ele crashou o app. Olha que engraçado. "You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting"

Comment: Da uma olhada na sua versão do Glide, para ser aceito o setTag, deve ser a versão 3.6.0

Comment: Estou na 3.7.0 ... Pelo que entendi eles removeram essa opção. É isso?

Comment: Encontrei uma pergunta em que cita exatamente essa questão, da uma olhada na solução, ve se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833627/error-you-must-not-call-settag-on-a-view-glide-is-targeting-when-use-glide

Comment: esse final int position tem algum problema pelo fato de ser final?