# onClick RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Estou seguindo esse tutorial de implementação de TabLayout e ViewPager com RecyclerView:

[TabLayout e ViewPager com RecyclerView](http://www.journaldev.com/12958/android-tablayout-viewpager)

Estou usando o referido projeto para testes de como pegar a ação do click no RecyclerView. Para complementar, estou seguindo esse post que trata desse assunto e do mesmo projeto no StackOverFlow:

[Post do StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033731/android-tablayout-and-viewpager-get-position-click-item)

O que eu fiz:

1. Criei a Interface ClickListener;
2. Instanciei a interface no adaptador do RecyclerView;
3. Usei a função de interface implementando o onClickListener no
   ViewHolder; e
4. Implementei a interface no fragment.

**Minha interface**

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void itemlistener(int position);
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TextItemViewHolder> {

String[] items;
ClickListener clicklistener;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(String[] items, ClickListener clicklistener) {
    this.items = items;
    this.clicklistener = clicklistener;
}

@Override
public TextItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_list_item, parent, false);
    return new TextItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TextItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(items[position]);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}
}
```

**TextItemViewHolder**

```
public class TextItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
private TextView textView;


public TextItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    clicklistener.itemlistener(getAdapterPosition());
}

public void bind(String text) {
    textView.setText(text);
}

}
```

**FragmentA**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements ClickListener{

RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_A);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items, this);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void itemlistener(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "RecyclerView position is: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Não consegue achar a referência

[image: Imagem relacionada à referência]

Porque está ocorrendo esse erro na implementação para o clique no RecyclerView?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a abordagem certa para pegar o click/posicao no RecyclerView?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159830/2541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não acha porque você não tem nenhum atributo do tipo ClickListener declarado na classe TextItemViewHolder.

Duas possíveis soluções:

1. Torne a classe TextItemViewHolder uma *inner class* de RecyclerViewAdapter.
   TextItemViewHolder usará o atributo declarado na RecyclerViewAdapter.
2. Declare o atributo na classe TextItemViewHolder e passe o *listener* quando a instanciar.

Comment: Ramaral , obrigado pelo vasto conteúdo disponibilizado, me ajudou muito. Vou me aprofundar mais nesses conteúdos.