# Clicar no Item do RecycleView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-adapter

Tenho um projeto e utilizo o `Navigation Drawer` Como layout, e inflo todos os `fragmentos`, pois bem houve a necessidade de ter `RecycleView`, nele recebo o resultado feito por um select, só que preciso também que ele seja clicável e pegue o resultado do item clicado.

não estou conseguindo fazer com o `RecycleView` seja clicável, pesquisei mas quando inflo o fragmento ele da erro, segue códigos.

Meu `Adapter`:

```
public class AvaliaAdpter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AvaliaAdpter.AvaliaHolder> {

    List<AvaliaViagem> listaAvalia;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public AvaliaAdpter(List<AvaliaViagem> listaAvalia) {
        this.listaAvalia = listaAvalia;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AvaliaHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View vista = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_avalia, viewGroup, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new AvaliaHolder(vista, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AvaliaAdpter.AvaliaHolder avaliaHolder, int i) {

        avaliaHolder.txtHorarios.setText(listaAvalia.get(i).getHorarios().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaAvalia.size();
    }

    public class AvaliaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtHorarios;

        public AvaliaHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            txtHorarios = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAvalia);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

E meu `onCreateView` no Fragmento:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avalie_viagem, container, false);

        getActivity().setTitle("Avalie sua Viagem");

        txtAvalia = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textoHorario);

        spinnerLinha = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_avalia_linha);
        final ArrayAdapter adapterSpLinha = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.sp_linha, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterSpLinha.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerLinha.setAdapter(adapterSpLinha);

        rbIda = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbIda_avalia);
        rbVolta = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbVolta_avalia);

        listarAvalia = new ArrayList<>();

        botaoConsultar = view.findViewById(R.id.btnConsultar_avaliacao);

        recyclerAvalia = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.idRecycler);
        recyclerAvalia.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
        recyclerAvalia.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AvaliaAdpter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                changeItem(position, "Clicado");
            }
        });

        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        botaoConsultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                linha = spinnerLinha.getSelectedItem().toString();

                SimpleDateFormat formataData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date data = new Date();
                String dataFormatada = formataData.format(data);
                String dataAtual = getWeek(dataFormatada);

                if (dataAtual.toString().equals("Domingo")) {
                    vDiaSemana = "1";
                } else if (dataAtual.toString().equals("Segunda-feira")) {
                    vDiaSemana = "2";
                } else if (dataAtual.toString().equals("Terça-feira")) {
                    vDiaSemana = "3";
                } else if (dataAtual.toString().equals("Quarta-feira")) {
                    vDiaSemana = "4";
                } else if (dataAtual.toString().equals("Quinta-feira")) {
                    vDiaSemana = "5";
                } else if (dataAtual.toString().equals("Sexta-feira")) {
                    vDiaSemana = "6";
                } else if (dataAtual.toString().equals("Sábado")) {
                    vDiaSemana = "7";
                }


                if (linha.toString().equals("Selecione a Linha")) {
                    vCidade = "0";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X MACHADOS")) {
                    vCidade = "6";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X TAQUARITINGA")) {
                    vCidade = "11";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X SANTA CRUZ")) {
                    vCidade = "12";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("TIMBAÚBA X ITAMBÉ")) {
                    vCidade = "21";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X CARPINA")) {
                    vCidade = "22";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X FEIRA NOVA")) {
                    vCidade = "23";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X LIMOEIRO")) {
                    vCidade = "25";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("GOIANA X TIMBAÚBA")) {
                    vCidade = "28";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("GOIANA X TIMBAÚBA(TUPAOCA)")) {
                    vCidade = "29";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X NAZARÉ")) {
                    vCidade = "30";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X PAUDALHO")) {
                    vCidade = "31";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("CARPINA X TIMBAÚBA")) {
                    vCidade = "32";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X LIMOEIRO S. EXP")) {
                    vCidade = "36";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X SURUBIM")) {
                    vCidade = "39";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X TRACUNHAÉM")) {
                    vCidade = "43";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X SÃO VICENTE(S.VICÊNCIA)")) {
                    vCidade = "47";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X SÃO VICENTE(TIMBAÚBA)")) {
                    vCidade = "48";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X SÃO VICENTE(B.AIRES)")) {
                    vCidade = "50";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X TIMBAÚBA")) {
                    vCidade = "51";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X SALGADINHO")) {
                    vCidade = "53";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X UMBURETAMA")) {
                    vCidade = "54";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X LAGOA DO CARRO")) {
                    vCidade = "55";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X LAGOA DE ITAENGA")) {
                    vCidade = "56";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X BUENOS AIRES")) {
                    vCidade = "57";
                } else if (linha.toString().equals("RECIFE X ALIANÇA")) {
                    vCidade = "58";
                }

                if (rbIda.isChecked()) {
                    vSentido = "I";
                } else if (rbVolta.isChecked()) {
                    vSentido = "V";
                }

                if (linha.toString().equals("Selecione a Linha")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Favor Selecionar uma Linha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (!vSentido.isEmpty()) {
                    carregarWEBService();
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Se eu comentar esse trecho do `onCreateView` ele infla mais também não posso testar o clic:

```
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AvaliaAdpter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                changeItem(position, "Clicado");
            }
        });
```

O que será.

Comment: A variável `mAdapter` foi inicializada?

Comment: Não tinha inicializado, daí inicializei com minha lista. o fragmento foi inflado mais o click não está funcionando.

Comment: Veja [Qual é a abordagem certa para pegar o click/posição no RecyclerView?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159904/2541).

Comment: Mano consegui, agora como faço pra pegar o valor do `TextView` de cada linha do `RecycleView` ?

Comment: Consegui, usei `minhalista.get(posicao).getvalor();` , vlw mesmo;